# Laravel 5 Undefined variable Controller 2 View

Tags: php, laravel

Im Going crazy with the undefined variable error in laravel , Hope someone could point out what im doing wrong, already tried several ways to pass variable from my controller to my view but nothings seems to work.
Thanks in advance

Controller:

```
   public function busquedaGet()
{
   return view('frontend.user.busquedaBoxeadores',compact('posts'));

}




public function busquedaPost(Request $request, BusquedaRepository $userRepo)

{
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'gender' => 'required|not_in:null',
        'weight' => 'required|not_in:null',
        'country' => 'required|not_in:null'
    ]);


    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect(route('busquedaPostA'))->withErrors($validator);
    }

     $posts=$userRepo->busquedaBoxers($request->all());
      //dd($posts);
    return view('frontend.user.busquedaBoxeadores',compact('posts'));

}
```

view:

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.app')

@section('title')
    {{{ trans('app.contrataBoxeadores') }}}
@endsection

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 visible-lg">
        <div class="side-bar">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="updates">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-update mg-top20">
          <div class="panel-heading">
           <h3 align="center">{{{ trans('app.red') }}} </h3>
          </div>
           <div class="panel-body"> 
                     {!! Form::open(['url' => route('busquedaPostA')]) !!}
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('gender', trans('app.gender')); !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('gender', ['null' => trans(''),'F' => trans('app.female'), 'M' => trans('app.male')], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('gender'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('gender') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('weight') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                   {!! Form::label('weight', trans('app.weight')); !!}
                                   {!! Form::select('weight', ['null' => trans(''),
                                   ' 1' => trans('Mini flyweight'),
                                   ' 2' => trans('Fyweight'),
                                   ' 3' => trans('Super flyweight'),
                                   ' 4' => trans('Bantamweight'),
                                   ' 5' => trans('Super bantamweight'),
                                   ' 6' => trans('Featherweight'),
                                   ' 7' => trans('Super featherweight'),
                                   ' 8' => trans('Lightweight'),
                                   ' 9' => trans('Super lightweight'),
                                   '10' => trans('Welterweight'),
                                   '11' => trans('Super welterweight'),
                                   '12' => trans('Middleweight'),
                                   '13' => trans('Super middleweight'),
                                   '14' => trans('Light heavyweight'),
                                   '15' => trans('Cruiserweight'),
                                   '16' => trans('Heavyweight')],
                                    null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('country'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('weight') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                 </div>
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('country') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('country', trans('country.countries')); !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('country', ['null' => trans(''),
                                    'us' => trans('country.united'), 'bz' => trans('country.brazil'), 'mx' => trans('country.mexico'), 'cl' => trans('country.colombia'),'ar' => trans('country.argentina'), 'ca' => trans('country.canada'), 'pu' => trans('country.peru'), 'vz' => trans('country.venezuela'), 'cl' => trans('country.chile'), 'ec' => trans('country.ecuador'), 'gt' => trans('country.guatemala'), 'cb' => trans('country.cuba'), 'hi' => trans('country.haiti'),  'bl' => trans('country.bolivia'), 'dr' => trans('country.dominican'), 'hnd' => trans('country.honduras'), 'pa' => trans('country.paraguay'), 'nic' => trans('country.nicaragua'),'slv' => trans('country.salvador'), 'cr' => trans('country.costa'), 'pnm' => trans('country.panama'), 'pr' => trans('country.puerto'), 'urg' => trans('country.uruguay'),'jam' => trans('country.jamaica'), 'tt' => trans('country.trinidad'), 'blz' => trans('country.belize'), 'brb' => trans('country.barbados'), 'ot' => trans('country.other')],
                                    null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('country'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('country') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                 {!! Form::submit(trans('app.buscar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block signup-btn']); !!} 
                                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>           
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>

     <div class="col-md-3 visible-lg"> 
     <p> Hello, {{ $posts }} </p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

routes

```
    Route::post('/profile/busquedaBoxeadores',['as' => 'busquedaPostA', 'uses' => 'UserController@busquedaPost']);
    Route::get('/profile/busquedaBoxeadores', ['as' => 'busquedaGetA', 'uses' => 'UserController@busquedaGet']);
```

repository

```
    public function busquedaBoxers(array $data, $source = 'site')
{
 $query = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id')
        ->join('boxings', 'users.id', '=', 'boxings.user_id')
        ->join('countries', 'users.id', '=', 'countries.user_id')           
        ->select('users.name', 'users.username', 'users.id')
        ->where('boxings.weight_id', '=', $data['weight'])
        ->where('user_profiles.gender', '=', $data['gender'])
        ->where('countries.country', '=', $data['country'])
        ->get();

        return $query;
}
```

Comment: add error description

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: this is what im getting :

Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\Users\Bof3ss37\Desktop\socialwall_v1.0.3\resources\views\frontend\user\busquedaBoxeadores.blade.php)

Comment: busque‌​daBoxeadores.blade.p‌​hp error in this view.. add more info about this file

Comment: Ok added the whole thing

Comment: `busquedaGet` method has no `$posts` variable in your controller

Comment: Im confuse on how to do it because I have to perform the validation on busquedaPost and make sure all fields are selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same view for both methods: `busquedaGet` and `busquedaPost` but in `busquedaGet` you're `compact`-ing variable `posts` that is not defined. So you can add empty string if you're not using them in get-method:

```
public function busquedaGet()
{
    $posts = [];
    return view('frontend.user.busquedaBoxeadores',compact('posts'));
}
```

And modify view. Replace:

```
<p> Hello, {{ $posts }} </p>
```

With:

```
<p> Hello,
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->username }}
@endforeach
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex

Ok I tried it but  now im getting this when I perfom the search 

htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\Users\Bof3ss37\Desktop\socialwall_v1.0.3\resources\views\frontend\user\busquedaBoxeadores.blade.php)

Comment: @CesarGarcia then you have to decide what $posts should be? If it's an array - define it as array and display it with foreach statement. Added example in answer

Comment: Thanks Man !!

It´s up an running !! Oohhh spent hours on this lol should have ask before oh well ..

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to display the posts as string in the blade, but it's not defined in `busquedaGet` and in `busquedaPost` it's a collection.

Hello, {{ $posts }}

First you need to define a default value for it in `busquedaGet` and then try to loop through the collection to display it's content.